# Dual-Boot : Linux/Windows (mobo & hotswap options related)

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, hotswapping, dualboot

I am currently running (successfully for the past 3 weeks) a dualboot system with :

- Windows 10 Pro 1909 for professionnal reasons and gaming [480GB SSD on Sata port 3]
- Arch Linux latest release for everything else [120 GB SSD on Sata port 4 with Hot swap]

I am using this [Enermax disk rack](https://www.enermax.com/home.php?fn=eng/product_a1_1_1&lv0=3&lv1=81&no=281) on Sata port 4 for Hot swap.

There was nothing wrong until today... the rack was always ON (ON/OFF switch). Yesterday I put it OFF on Windows after ejecting properly. (I haven't even removed the disk physically)

Rebooting now, the MOBO won't see the disk as bootable, the option isn't available in the boot list.

I've tried rebooting, disconnecting Windows SSD, nothing seems to fix the problem. BIOS settings :

- Secure boot keys are cleared
- Type of OS is already "Other OS"

I boot using UEFI on both systems.
Also I should say that there is EFI partitions on both disks, the standard Windows install on 480GB SSD and 512MB EFI partition with GRUB2 on Linux SSD. If you should ask why, it's because I want them both to boot even if the other is not inside.

I found this behaviour very curious and I remembered when I was installing Arch the first time I encountered the same issue when rebooting into Windows after putting the rack on OFF. Installation was not complete so I thought it was a misconfiguration of the partition table so I reinstalled instead.

Do you have any idea ?

I've never seen something like it.
Hardware specs :

- Z170-A
- i7 6700K
- 32GB RAM

Thank you all,

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706645/bios-not-recognize-internal-drive-as-bootable-after-disconnecting-and-connecting) regarding a similar issue. It was strange for me at first to get this since I had a X220 Lenovo laptop which was fine with disconnecting and reconnecting different UEFI boots to change systems.

If someone sees this, I only want a diagnosis of the problem because I know how to fix it, I just want to stop it from happening again.

Reinstalling a boot loader will surely fix my boot.

I think it's what Rod Smoth says about EFI being different from BIOS and possibly getting wipe if you disconnect disks... What do you think ?